# Love triangle between Spy, Nazi commander & Resistance Soldier in occupied France

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to find out what movie I have seen a few years ago.

The action takes place in occupied France if I remember correctly. The first part is more like love story between a man and a woman. After this man enlists in the army and leaves to fight, the woman  apparently has an affair with a local nazi commander or something. When the man comes home finds out about the two and tries to convince her to leave him. Unfortunately she can't tell him the real reason why is she involved with the nazi guy, but later the man finds out that she actually enlisted as a spy for the French resistance :D

In the end, the french resistance manages to overtake the nazi occupation, but the woman gets caught by french people and she is considered a traitor because everyone who lived there saw her with the nazi commander.

The man tries to find her, but she eventually gets killed by the angry mob :(

It has one of the most frustrating movie endings I have ever seen.

Comment: can u please add when the movie might have been released. contemporary or classic?

Comment: definitely after 90, probably around 2000...

Comment: Why would you want to recover a movie with a frustrating ending? :P

Comment: [Charlotte Gray](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0245046/) might be the movie you're describing.

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway [the ending seems different (spoiler alert)](http://www.ruinedendings.com/film1915plot)

Comment: I found it! It was "Head in the clouds"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's "[Head in the clouds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338097/)"  Since you said it is ;)

From [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338097/):

> HEAD IN THE CLOUDS is a sweeping romantic drama set in 1930's England,
>   Paris, and Spain. Gilda Bessé shares her Paris apartment with an Irish
>   schoolteacher, Guy Malyon, and Mia, a refugee from Spain. As the world
>   drifts toward war, Gilda defiantly pursues her hedonistic lifestyle
>   and her burgeoning career as a photographer. But Guy and Mia feel
>   impelled to join the fight against fascism, and the three friends are
>   separated - seemingly forever

Comment: Are you sure? Description looks like Black book .

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3120861696/tt0389557?ref_=tt_ov_i

Comment: Didn't you say it was in you comments?

Comment: It's not me, another Alex

Comment: ah, well that Alex asked the question and said it was the answer so....